# Division in modular arithmetic

Tags: math, modular, modular-arithmetic

If X = (a*b)mod(c), and we know the value of "b" and "c" but not of "a", how can we find (a)mod(c)?

Can we do it as  X divided by (b)mod(c) or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion doesn't work.

For example

```
(3 * 4 ) mod 7 = 5
but 3 mod 5 != 5 / (4 mod 7) = 5/4
```

In this case we could note that

```
(4*2 ) mod 7 = 1
```

and then

```
(2 * ((3 * 4) mod 7) mod 7
= 24 mod 7 = 3 = 3 mod 7
```

and in general if b and c have no common divisors, then there is a b' with

```
(b'*b ) mod c = 1
```

and then

```
(b' * ((a*b) mod c) ) mod c
= (a* ((b'*b) mod c)) mod c
= (a*1) mod c
= a mod c
```

Given b and c with no common divisors you can find b' as above via the [extended Euclid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)